# How I can create workflow at runtime in .Net

Tags: .net-3.5, workflow-foundation

I'm using .Net framework 3.5, VS IDE to work with windows application. I have requirement to Create State machine Workflow at runtime. That is, I need to define my states, Activities n target state in one windows form and based on that I need to create entire workflow at runtime. I require persistence and tracking too for the same. Can anybody tell me how I can achieve this.

I have thought of XAML based workflow, but still not getting proper idea.

Comment: Hint: A workflow is an activity composed of other. child, activities.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx).  There are [virtual labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa740389.aspx) if you want to check out the technology.  Edit per comment:  Ah, I see.  There is a good series on that at [WF - How to Make A Workflow Dynamic?](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/08/28/4322.aspx)

Comment: @JP: He knows about WF. He needs to build the workflow dynamically, at runtime.

Comment: i know abt tech.. i have already worked on it...but i havent created at runtime...n in labs threre is many thing other than dynamic creation... any other help please..

Comment: hi 
its not meeting requirement again.... the link dat u sent me is for dynamic changes...n not dynamic creation...i m supposed to create worklflow based on input data at runtime..n dat to from scratch...